# CSS: How the backgrounds can extend the border and overlap?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a navigation bar as shown in image below (a) with the following code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="unselected">Step 1</li>
  <li class="selected">Step 2</li>
  <li class="unselected">Step 3</li>
  <li class="unselected">Step 4</li>
  <li class="unselected">Step 5</li>
</ul>
```

[image: The navigation bar]

I want to have one background image for unselected steps (d) and one for the selected step (c). For simplicity let's assume Step 1 and Step 5 use the same background as well.
I want to adjust the button background in HTML only with a class name.

The question is how can I achieve the result with CSS? I just want to know how *background of two neighbor elements can overlap each other*?

Edit: the steps are links. the background is a transparent PNG file preferably only containing the blue or gray shape and its border.

Comment: Do you need the hit areas to be precise?

Comment: Give me a moment and I'll have something up and running.  It won't use 'overlapping' backgrounds, though.  You'll see.

Comment: @thirtydot, I'm fascinated as to what you'll say if he replies 'yes'

Comment: @AlexStack See my post for a robust answer with tips besides on how to fix this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536665/css-how-the-backgrounds-can-extend-the-border-and-overlap/6537376#6537376

Comment: @Levi Morrison: thanks, I made some small edits to make it fit my special application. The final result is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Aptfw/1/

Comment: @shanethehat: I might have posted an answer based off this: http://www.joecritchley.com/demos/slanted-nav/.

Comment: I shall bookmark that for proper study, looks neat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/99LhB/**

**Notes:**

- **Click-boxes will be messed up on diagonals.**  I just realized that this will always be the case. I'd decrease the width of the arrow if I were you to help avoid this issue.  I would also add a hover state which would help clarify which one you are hovering on.  If they aren't hyperlinks, this doesn't matter: feel free to remove those css rules.
- **HTML simplicity makes for CSS complexity** in this case.  There are less classes to worry about, but now we rely on CSS selectors.  I would personally choose this way over the other, but that's a personal choice.
- **There's only one image.** Uses a CSS sprite to accomplish this. It also speeds up the webpage a little.
- Shows how it looks for all 5 steps.

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I need. BTW, your code is like a poem! Enjoyed reading it! PS. I don't have enough reputation to vote on answers but +1!

Comment: I cleaned it up a little bit to match my website structure. Here is the final version: http://jsfiddle.net/Aptfw/1/

Comment: I'm thinking how it is possible to have it color-independent. I mean being able to try different colors for normal, hover and selected state in CSS without requiring to reproduce the PNG file for background every time.

Comment: Indeed, this is some beautifull CSS use, but broken on IE < 8 :(

Comment: @Clement Herreman, it seems to work in my IE (version 9 on Win7-64)

Comment: @AlexStack: as I said, it broken for IE where version < 8 (IE 7 & 6 mainly). Might not be a problem, depending on what BC you have to maintain.

Comment: @Clement Herreman, if Google has quite supporting IE<8, then I feel like I can too.  I make web-apps, so it's nice. For general web, though, I can see what you mean.  I usually just add some JavaScript that adds some class to make it all work properly if it's needed.

Comment: @Levi Agreed, but you can't always quite supporting a type of browser, depending what and whom you're developing for. On the project I'm working currently, I need to be compatible with IE 6 (enjoy!). You prefere using graceful degradation, I'm usually more a progressive enhancement ^^.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this. what you want to do is use a negative margin.

```
.someclass {
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

That should overlap the each of the elements (if applied to all li objects).

Comment: To do it this way, you'd also have to apply z-indexing to get the layers to work properly.

Comment: That's right, should be easy enough to add z-index to the selected css class though.

Comment: Yup, he can either add z-index individually if the elements are known or with javascript if they're unknown. Here's a fiddle: with this solution and a jQuery z-index script: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/wvqg4/

Comment: However, if the steps are hyperlinks, then I do NOT recommend this answer.  The hover click-boxes will be deceiving, as the elements to the left must be on top of the ones to the right.

Comment: @Levi: agreed. In general way, overlaping is something I'm trying to avoid, to improve maintainability and easiness.

Comment: magin-left helped to align the images. But now it has a new problem: the text within the buttons is shifter toward left. I used padding-left to compensate but it didn't help.

Comment: @AlexStack, take a look at my answer.  One-liners rarely address all the issues. It doesn't have any upvotes at the moment because it came late to the scene, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

They can't overlap only the background, but html element might be stacked. However I'd recommend such a solution only if you have no other.

In your visual example, I guess that must be something like that :

Html :

```
<ul>
  <li class="before_selected">Step 1</li>
  <li class="selected">Step 2</li>
  <li class="after_selected">Step 3</li>
  <li class="unselected">Step 4</li>
  <li class="unselected">Step 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
.unselected {
  background-image: url('all_grey.jpg');
}
.before_selected {
  background-image: url('left_grey_right_blue.jpg');
}
.after_selected {
  background-image: url('left_blue_right_grey.jpg');
}
.selected {
  background-image: url('all_blue.jpg');
}
```

Comment: You answered his question, but not his *real* question: *How can I make this navigation work?*

Comment: "The question is how can I achieve the result with CSS? I just want to know how background of two neighbor elements can overlap each other?" I'm giving the OP answers he's asking : no you can't, and here is the CSS to achieve such effect.

Comment: All those extra classes are verbose, I'll post an example shortly.